# Specific page for each user, php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building an application. What I am tryinf to do is that when I user log in to have a specific page for each user. I have realised this for the first page. So when the user log in, the next page is a page that contains his name, and a calendar. What I want to do now is that when the user click in a date of the calendar, only the activities of this user are called from the database. My problem is that after I ma loged in whith a user profile, and when I click on one date of the calendar, it shows me not only the activities of this user but also the activities of other user...How can I solve this? Please help me...
Below is my code:

Here is the part of index page where user log in:

```
<form method="GET" action="signin.php" >  
    <table class="formtable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="text" type="text" id="email_id" name="email" value="Adresa emailit" required="required" onfocus="changefocus(this,'Adresa emailit')" onblur="fillemptyform(this,'Adresa emailit')">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="text" type="password" id="pass_id" name="pass" value="Password" required="required" onfocus="changefocus(this,'Password')" onblur="fillemptyform(this,'Password')">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
 </form>
```

Here is the sign in.php page that opens as sonn as the user log in: ( I have shown only the part where php is used)

```
<?php 
    //kontrollo per submitin e formes
    if(isset($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['pass'])) {
        $Emaili=$_GET['email'];
        $Fjalekalimi=$_GET['pass'];
        mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die("Smund te lidhet me serverin");
        mysql_select_db("axhenda") or die("Kjo databaze nuk u gjet");
        $userquery = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM perdoruesi where Emaili = '$Emaili' AND  Fjalekalimi = '$Fjalekalimi'") or die("Kjo query nuk mund te plotesohet");
        if(mysql_num_rows($userquery) !=1) { 
            die ("Ky perdorues nuk u gjet");
        }

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $Emri =$row['Emri'];
            $Mbiemri =$row['Mbiemri'];
            $Emaili =$row['Emaili'];
            $Fjalekalimi =$row['Fjalekalimi'];
            $Aksesi =$row['Aksesi'];
        }

?>

<?php
    } else die("Bosh");
?> 

<div class="miresevini">
    <span style="color: rgb(4, 38, 73); font-weight: bold;"> Welcome(</span>
    <span style="color: #b2d7fd"><?php echo $Emri;?>, <?php echo $Mbiemri;?></span>
    <span style="color: rgb(4, 38, 73);font-weight: bold;">)</span>
</div>
```

And here is the kalendar.php file, which is called when I click to a date , and it shows all the activities of that date

```
<body>      
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Lidhja me databazen nuk mund te kryhet' .mysql_error(). ' </body></html>');
    }

    if(!mysql_select_db("Axhenda",$con))
        die('Nuk mund te hapet databaza Axhenda'.mysql_error(). '</body></html>');

    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]'");

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

<div class="title"> Aktivitetet per daten <?php print ("$_POST[dataoutput]"); ?></div>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="delete.php">
    <table >
        <th>
            <th ><strong>Emri </strong></th>
            <th ><strong>Pershkrimi </strong></th>
            <th><strong>Ora</strong></th>
        </th>
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td ><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['Id_Akt']; ?>"></td>
<td style="font-size:0.9em"><?php echo $row['Emri']; ?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['Pershkrimi']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Ora']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>


</table>
<input class="button" name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete" style="margin-left:40%; margin-top:100px; width:15%">

    </form>

</body>
```

Please help me. What should I do in order to show only the activitiies of log in user ... The tables that are used in mysql are two:

```
Perdoruesi(Id_Per, Emri, Mbiemri, Emaili,Pass, Akses)   saves information about the user
```

and

```
Aktiviteti(Id_Akt, Perd_Id, Emri, Pershkrimi, Date, Time), saves the information about the activity.
```

and Perd_Id is a Foreign key of Id_Per in the table Perdoruesi. I have also build the relation between foreign key and primary key, but I still does not get only the activities of the specific user....Please help me. Thanks in advance!

I modified the signin.php file like this:( I add the SESSION part)

```
<?php 

//kontrollo per submitin e formes
if(isset($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['pass']))
{$Emaili=$_GET['email'];
 $Fjalekalimi=$_GET['pass'];
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die("Smund te lidhet me serverin");
mysql_select_db("axhenda") or die("Kjo databaze nuk u gjet");
$userquery = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM perdoruesi where Emaili = '$Emaili' AND  Fjalekalimi = '$Fjalekalimi'") or die("Kjo query nuk mund te plotesohet");
if(mysql_num_rows($userquery) !=1)
{ die ("Ky perdorues nuk u gjet");
   }

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {$Id_Per=$row['Id_Per'];
   $Emri =$row['Emri'];
   $Mbiemri =$row['Mbiemri'];
   $Emaili =$row['Emaili'];
   $Fjalekalimi =$row['Fjalekalimi'];
   $Aksesi =$row['Aksesi'];
   }



?>



<?php
}
  else die("Bosh");

?>

<?php
session_start();
// store session data
 $_SESSION['Id_Per'] = 1;
?>
```

and modified the kalendar.php like this:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]' and Perd_Id= $_SESSION['Id_Per']");
```

But it still gives me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\kalendar.php on line 63
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please can you help me? I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you are loading the data with the query

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]'");
```

You are selecting all the data for that date. You will need todo something like

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]' and Email = '$_SESSION['email']'");
```

In the above query I am assuming you are storing the users email in session. If not you will need to be able to have access to it some how. That way you are only selecting the records that have the current users email address associated with it. This is also assuming you are storing the email address of each user with their event for the day.

---

Update

Example Login

```
<?php 
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
           if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username']) {
               // Check to see if username and password is correct
               // Should return user if correct else false
               $user = authenticate($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
               if($user){
                  $_SESSION['user'] = $user['username'];
                  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
                  $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
               } else {
                    // Handel user not being authenticated
           } else {
               // Handle the username and password not being present
           }
      }
?>
```

Example get information for db.

```
<?php
         $q = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Data = " . $_POST['item'] . " and user_id = " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
         $result = mysql_query($q);
         // Do something with the result.
?>
```

Comment: I want to make it acccording the id of user not according to email:

Comment: I want  to make it according the user id not according the email. I try to make it like this: $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]' and Perd_Id= '$_SESSION['$Id_Per']");  but it gives me am error :Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\agenda\kalendar.php on line 57....it gives me the same error if I make it for email like you tell me....please help me...what can I do?

Comment: You can always store the user's information in session. You can do this by $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1. That way you have access to that data anywhere in the application.

Comment: But how can I store the user information in session? Please can you tell me? sorry for my question but I am a begginerr to php

Comment: Where I shuld put $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1 at kalendari.php or at signin.php

Comment: To store something in session you will use the session superglobal `$_SESSION`. It is nothing more than an associative array that is available in any scope. To store something in session you `$_SESSION['KEY'] = value`. Where key is username, email, id, etc. To retrieve something from session you call it using a key. eg `$_SESSION['key']`.

for example.
    (Setting a user id)
    `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1`

    (Getting user id from from session)
    `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']`

The above bit of code will set user_id in session to one, and the set $user_id = 1

Comment: You will assign the session value at login, so you can access it later. You will need to unset that value when the user logs out. eg `unset($_SESSION['user_id']);`

Comment: I modified my code like I post above but it still gives me a problem..please can you help me...thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If I am to continue to help I will need to know what new problem has come up.

Comment: I have published above the error it gives to me..and how I have modified the code...Have I modified it right and how can I solve the error?

Comment: That error is because of the way you built the string. You can escape the them by using \' or concatenate the string. I also updated my example